# Does eof() look at lines or data? C++

Tags: eof, getline

Let's say I am trying to read in data line by line from a file called input.txt. There's about 20 lines and each line consists of 3 different data types. If I use this code:

```
while(!file.eof){ ..... }
```

Does this function look at only one data type from each line per iteration, or does it look at the all the data types at once for each line per iteration--so the next iteration would look at the next line instead of the next data type?

Many thanks.

Comment: You forgot the parens: `while (!file.eof())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.eof()` looks at the end of file flag. The flag is set *after* you run over the end of the file. This is not desirable.

A great blog post on how this works and best practice can be found [here](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/reading-files.html).

Basically, use

```
std::string line;
while(getline(file, line)) { ... }
```

or

```
while (file >> some_data) { ... }
```

as it will notice errors and the end of the file at the correct time and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. With "file >> some_data," does the >> operator sequentially read in data from the same line once it is called or would it always start from the same spot in the file regardless of which line it is at? Thanks.

Comment: Most file code reads the file and advances through it. Usually to look but not move through the file a `peek` command is used.